Build errors 4094 since upgrading from Angular 17 to Angular 18
I get this error at random time when building my app. This error happens every other time after I modify a file. I am using ng build --watch to build everytime I change something.
An unhandled exception occurred: UNKNOWN: unknown error, copyfile 

[error] Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, copyfile 'E:\path\to_web_app\src\assets\img\illustrations\group\png\yellow\cat.png' -> 'E:\path\to_web_app\public\u\assets\img\illustrations\group\png\yellow\cat.png'
at async Object.copyFile (node:internal/fs/promises:622:10)
at async E:\path\to_web_app\node_modules\@angular\build\src\tools\esbuild\utils.js:223:13
at async Promise.all (index 29)
at async emitFilesToDisk (E:\path\to_web_app\node_modules\@angular\build\src\tools\esbuild\utils.js:237:9)
at async writeResultFiles (E:\path\to_web_app\node_modules\@angular\build\src\tools\esbuild\utils.js:218:9)
at async writeAndEmitOutput (E:\path\to_web_app\node_modules\@angular\build\src\builders\application\build-action.js:177:9)
at async runEsBuildBuildAction (E:\path\to_web_app\node_modules\@angular\build\src\builders\application\build-action.js:161:19)
at async buildApplicationInternal (E:\path\to_web_app\node_modules\@angular\build\src\builders\application\index.js:61:5)
at async handleAsyncIterator (E:\path\to_web_app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\api.js:35:28)

errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'copyfile',

I run ng build right after and all works again for couple of changes and the error is back again and again.  Has anyone came acrross a similar problem and has a way of solving this error 4094? It is bugging me a lot
